# Opening and viewing the content of a .sqlite file

Tags: iphone, sqlite

How can I open and see the records, tables, etc in a `.sqlite` execution file which has been added to in an iPhone application? Are there any tutorials for doing this?

Comment: Here's a solution for the **terminal/ command line**. 

From your shell, open the database file with `sqlite3 <name-of-db-file>` . To list the tables in the database use `.tables` . For displaying more sqlite commands use `.help` . To see the contents of a table named "musicstore_albums", use sql commands, e.g. `select * from musicstore_albums;` . Don't forget the semi-colon at the end.


Quit with `.quit` :)

Answer (score 18):

open firefox, go to: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/
then download and install. after installing click on `Tools-->SQLite Manager-->click on the link..connect database..-->give the path of .sqlite file. and open`

Answer (score 14):

if you use firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817

> #### SQLite Manager
>
> Manage any SQLite database on your computer...
>
> Features:
>
> - Manage any SQLite database on your computer.
> - An intuitive heirarchical tree showing database objects.
> - Helpful dialogs to manage tables, indexes, views and triggers.
> - You can browse and search the tables, as well as add, edit, delete and duplicate the records.
> - Facility to execute any sql query.
> - The views can be searched too.
> - A dropdown menu helps with the sql syntax thus making writing sql easier.
> - Easy access to common operations through menu, toolbars, buttons and context-menu.
> - Export tables/views/database in csv/xml/sql format. Import from csv/xml/sql (both UTF-8 and UTF-16).
> - Possible to execute multiple sql statements in Execute tab.
> - You can save the queries.
> - Support for ADS on Windows...

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:
http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks, Amber, that works like a champ; I've used firefox in the past, and their sqlite-manager is an awesome tool (kind of like a Database Workbench for SQLite), but since I am now a Chrome user, this SQLite Browser is preferable - thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

My personal favourite tool for working with sqlite databases is [sqliteManager](http://www.sqlabs.net/sqlitemanager.php) it costs money but its money well spent in my book.

Comment: How much easier is it to use than the SQLite Manager plugin for Firefox?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't know because I don't use Firefox - but I find it so so easy to use its become the only tool I use for anything involving sqlite databases